# Cannot change TextView style in oncreate

Tags: android, fonts, runnable, oncreate

I'm not able to change the text style via the function `initFonts()` in the `onCreate()` function of my class. There is no error, but nothing happens. I am running a runnable which is an infinite loop (delay of 1 second). Is this a problem?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        initFonts();

        // Start a load dialog
        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        progressdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressdialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressdialog.show();


        // Start updating all lists
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                updateList();
            }
        }; 

        // Keep it running
        runnable.run();         
    }
```

I am changing the fonts in the `initFonts()` method:

```
TextView cur = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.current);
TextView plus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.plus);
TextView min = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.min);

cur.setTextSize(150);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font.ttf");  
cur.setTypeface(font);

plus.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
min.getBackground().setAlpha(45);
```

Comment: check your font.ttf file.. is it in any folder.?

Comment: yes it is in the folder

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "foldername/font.ttf");  
cur.setTypeface(font);
```

Comment: it is the textview not working. I even can't set a listener to it